# jetpackCompose mutablestate not saving the state

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a auth screen where I have textUser on which I have by remember to save state but when I navigate to a screen and then come back to the screen by pressing back button the textuser var is reset for some reason. Isn't the whole purpose of mutuablestate() to solve this?

```
    var textUser by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
 TextField(
                    value = dialCode ?: "+91",
                    onValueChange = { dialCode = it },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
                    modifier = Modifier
//                        .padding(top = 5.dp)
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                        .clickable(onClick = { navController.navigate(NavScreens.Country.route) }),
                    enabled = false,
                    singleLine = true,
                    label = { Text(text = "") },
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                        disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        focusedLabelColor = Color.Gray,
                        unfocusedLabelColor = Color.Gray
                    ),
                    readOnly = true,
                    textStyle = TextStyle(color = colorResource(id = R.color.login_text_enabled)),
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
                        .also { interactionSource ->
                            LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
                                interactionSource.interactions.collect {
                                    if (it is PressInteraction.Release) {
                                        navController.navigate(NavScreens.Country.route)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
TextField(
                value = textUser,
                onValueChange = { textUser = it },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
                label = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.email_id_or_mobile_number)) },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = hidePadding.dp).align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                    disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    focusedLabelColor = Color.Gray,
                    unfocusedLabelColor = Color.Gray,
                    focusedTrailingIconColor = Color.Gray
                ),
                singleLine = true,
                textStyle = TextStyle(color = colorResource(id = R.color.login_text_enabled))
            )
```

so I'm expecting for textuser to be same value even after coming back to auth screen

Comment: If you want the value saved, is there a reason you aren't using `rememberSaveable` instead of `remember`?

Comment: there's no feature of rotaion on login screen so i didnt used it. but even after using it, it resets the data

Answer (score 1):

None of `remember` or `rememberSaveable` works in your situation. `remember` and `rememberSaveable` will remember the latest value during recomposition. However, when you navigate back from login screen to the upper screen, the whole login screen is disposed. Then when you come back to the login screen, it is doing initial composition again. That's why the `textUser` variable is being reset.

You should consider `ViewModel` for persisting the `textUser`. The ViewModel lifecycle is longer than the Composable function, so even you nav back from login screen, the data in the ViewModel is not reset.

Here is a good tutorial about ViewModel: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#0

Answer (score 0):

Using `rememberSaveable` helps the state persist on orientation changes or navigation.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#restore-ui-state

Comment: i tried using it it survives the rotation but still the value is being rest